# how can i make my webpage load faster with or without jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery

i was wondering about fast page load for google and facebook. how it is possible... If we say they have high quilified servers then visit http://www.iconarchive.com/ and type some thing in its search box and hit enter and see the same load time as google and facebook.

let me know about that rocket science.

Comment: You need to ask a question. What specifically are you interested in knowing?

Comment: What are *high quilified servers*? The best thing that you can do for your site is just get faster internet for your servers (if it's small-scale).

Comment: so what will be the specs for faster servers for facebook like community

Comment: You're focusing totally on the wrong sort of thing. Your code is likely to matter far more than the servers they're hosted on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a ton of ways to optimize pageload times.

You can use tools like  yslow for firebug to learn and test some of them. On top of that there is a gazillion books and blogposts about it, and if you search here on SO you will also find tons of information about it.

I will give you a hint though: it is not rocketscience, but it is not simple enough to fit easily into a single post like this - read, study and learn :)

Here is a place to start:

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Answer (score 1):

Facebook use [HipHop PHP](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/) and a lot of servers. But HipHop is very fast.

Google use some storage engines and search engines for very fast search restults that are scaled on many systems.

Answer (score 0):

You should minify your javascript with [Jsmin](http://crockford.com/javascript/jsmin) or [yui](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/). This helps and saves bandwidth.
You should enable compression on your webserver, take a look at [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) if you are using apache2. You also could upgrade hardware on your server, but optimizing code gives generaly better results.

Finaly, take a look at the [firefox page speed extension](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/speed/page-speed/). This extension will give you hints on what to optimize.